# Better way to write this?

Tags: jquery

any better way to write this ?

`$(this).parent().parent().find(" dd ul").toggle();`

---

update..

I am trying to create a dropdown using the script here 
http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/07/28/reinventing-drop-down-with-css-jquery.aspx

however the script works only for one instance of list and my code works good for multiple instances. Just curious if there is another better way to get parent of a parent in jQuery

Comment: We'll need to see your markup.

Comment: If you have a `ul` in your markup then the odds are you should have multiple adjacent sibling `dd` elements instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method to find the parent `dd` element and go from there:

```
$(this).closest('dd').find('ul').toggle();
```

Comment: closet method goes through the DOM the opposite way ? I mean from bottom to top ?

Comment: Correct, it finds the first parent that matches the selector going up the DOM.